# Почему бин равен нулю?

Tags: java, spring

Я новичок в спринге. В папку package1 eсть класс Worker с одним методом working, класс Logger и класс Start, в котором все запускается:
package package1;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class Worker {

    public void working() {
        System.out.println("I'm working");
    }
}



package package1;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class Logger {


    @Pointcut("execution (* *(..)) )")
    public void workerMethod() {
    }

    ;

    @Before("workerMethod()")
    public void logMethodBefore() {
        System.out.println("Logger Before");
    }

    @After("workerMethod()")
    public void logMethodAfter() {
        System.out.println("Logger After");
    }

    @Around("workerMethod()")
    public void logMethod() {

        System.out.println("It's logMethod");
    }
}


package package1;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("package1\\workerContext.xml");
        Worker worker = (Worker) context.getBean("worker");
        System.out.println(worker);
        worker.working();
    }
}
```

И файл workerContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="package1"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

</beans>
```

Почему-то при запуске объект worker у меня равен null и его метод working() не срабатывает. Почему?

Comment: Где и как вызываете `Worker`?

Comment: в классе Start я его создаю с помощью getBean